Shared memory pointer causes segfault when trying to set value
I was trying to make a process that access a shared memory segment created by another process. Everything was working fine I can get id of the shared memory segment, the pointer to the segment and I can detach the process from it. The problem started after i tried to write a singular character on memory using the pointer given by shmat.
It doesn't matter if I try to read or write using the pointer, it throws a segfault.
This is the code of the process that creates the shared memory:
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "shmlib.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int shmid;        // Variable ocn el identificador del espacio en memoria

    shmid = getMemoryBlock();
    if (shmid<0){
        printf("Error al inicializar la memoria");
        exit(1);
    };

    // Le mostramos al usuario el id del espacio de memoria compartida.
    printf("El espacio de memoria con id %d fue creado exitosamente.", shmid);
    return 0;
}

This is the code of the process that access the shared memory:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "shmlib.h"
#include <sys/ipc.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char* mem;
    
    mem = attachToMemory();   // Puntero donde almacenaremos la direccion de memoria de nuestro segmento compartido
    if (mem==NULL){
        printf("No se puede acceder a la memoria compartida\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *it;
    it = mem;
    *it = 'c'; //This causes the segfault
    return 0;
}

And this is the code for shmlib.c that contains attachToMemory
#include "shmlib.h"

const int shmsize = 32;
const key_t key = 4629;

int getMemoryBlock(){
    return shmget(key, shmsize,  IPC_CREAT | 0666);
}

char * attachToMemory(){
    int shmid = getMemoryBlock();
    char *result;
    if (shmid==-1){
        return NULL;
    }

    result = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if (result == (char *)-1){
        return NULL;
    }
    return result;
}

I tried changing the permissions to see if it was part of the problem but it didn't work. Also I tried to see it shmat throw any error but errno always returned 0.
So here I am asking for some help.

It would be better to make shmsize and key function parameters rather than global variables.

Edit the question to provide a [mre]. To start with that, get rid of all the input: Delete the scanf and atoi calls and use only hard-coded values. (This is for debugging, not for production.)

What is the output from ipcs -m?  The memory segment likely already exists, and if you created it with an earlier version of the code with wrong permissions it will still exist with wrong permissions.

shmsize is 0 which could be the problem.

shmsize is set by an input parameter.

I thought this at first, then I saw scanf("%d", &shmsize);

It's not because when I check if the shared memory was created with ipcs -m it shows the size the user provided.

i have copy pasted your code and tried on ubuntu with gcc. Some changes i created for gcc instread of cpp like got rid of bool. I do not see segmentation fault and it works fine. I am linking executable with shmlib.c instread of separate lib if you are creating shmlib.so or shmlib.a. ipcs command also shows shm created. command to access shared mem i am using is ./shmaccess 512 1 10 10
